# Mercedes-Benz Antos 2540 wrong key issue

Tags: starting, ignition-key

I reside in Luanda, Angola. I got a second hand Truck, an **Mercedes-Benz Antos 2540**. It is *no longer recognizing its ignition Key*. What to do please?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To my knowledge, because of how Mercedes does their thing with keys, if it isn't working, about the only way to get it fixed is to take it to a MB service center and have them do their thing. They are close held with the programming of their keys.

Comment: Does the fob open the doors? What makes you think the key isn't recognized?

Comment: Does the FOB/ignition key have a battery?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: How to place a picture here? It does not have any door to open. The bordcomputer is showing "Wrong Key", so the truck can not start

Comment: They are two keys in one. The movable metalic part serves to lock and unlock the doors. The other part has got an Infrared windows that when inserted in the igniton hole, estalishes the contact so tha car can recognize it and allows to push for start

Comment: To add a photo, edit your question, then click on the icon that looks like a mountain.

Comment: It does have a battery @TomatalaJose, you just don't see it. If the battery burns out or goes dead the key will stop communicating with the car's engine computer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.